# What does "grade" and "slack" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Remain alert for conditions that can cause **slack** action (e.g. train
>   brake, change in **grade** or change in speed).
>
> Remain alert for conditions that can cause abrupt changes in speed,
>   e.g., train braking, changes in **grade**, wet or icy tracks, and entering
>   or leaving a rail yard or train station.

What does "grade" and "slack" mean in these sentences? It seems that none of the definitions found in a dictionary fits in this context. Does "grade" also mean gear (gear shift)?

Comment: If you ever post a quote, please remember to state the source, and link to it if possible. In this case this looks like technical writing for operating a locomotive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These terms are North American railway ("railroad") related.

Slack action is what happens to the cars of a train when it changes speed suddenly. The cars are not rigidly coupled. If the train slows down, each car can try to run into the one in front; if it speeds up, each car will try to pull back. Both these actions place a strain on the couplings between the cars, and, especially with a long heavy train, if not controlled, can cause the train to break apart.

> In railroading, slack action is the amount of free movement of one car
>   before it transmits its motion to an adjoining coupled car. This free
>   movement results from the fact that in railroad practice cars are
>   loosely coupled, and the coupling is often combined with a
>   shock-absorbing device, a "draft gear," which, under stress,
>   substantially increases the free movement as the train is started or
>   stopped. Loose coupling is necessary to enable the train to bend
>   around curves and is an aid in starting heavy trains, since the
>   application of the locomotive power to the train operates on each car
>   in the train successively, and the power is thus utilized to start
>   only one car at a time.

[Slack action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slack_action)

The grade of a section of land, road, railway is its slope, inclination or gradient:

> The grade (also called slope, incline, gradient, mainfall, pitch or
>   rise) of a physical feature, landform or constructed line refers to
>   the tangent of the angle of that surface to the horizontal.

[Grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grade_(slope))